# Implementing Datafeed in AMP Email

Tags: xslt, amp-html, amp-email

What we want to do is tell `AMP` to place the dynamic content (based on XSLT) within the AMP mail.

In the non AMP emails our emailclient (copernica) is listing data with the following code:

`{loadfeed feed=$xmlurl xslt="XSLT_AMP_PS1"}` where PS1 is product image.

Our goal is to get our datafeed into AMP for email to show dynamic content.
We have challenge to implement this dynamicvalue in XLST language in the AMP code.

please see below the AMP code and the dynamic field we wish to implement between the "".

```
<amp-img src="**Dynamic XSLT data**" width="400" height="300" alt="a sample image"></amp-img>
```

Comment: you may have to use an `amp-list` endpoint served using HTTPS+CORS

Comment: How does your code look like for non-AMP emails?

Comment: {loadfeed feed=$xmlurl xslt="WS_XML_title_PS3"}

Comment: I think you need to reach out to your email provider's support. If I understand correctly, they are responsible for this substitution to work and there's nothing AMP-specific here.